# Why isn't a single form element is not returning value in the controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

In my Form 3 fields including a hidden.and the rest of the values are perfectly returns in controller ,But the value in the hidden field is not getting .
the value in the hidden field is passing from an anchor tag using java script.
**The value for the hidden field is passing from here**

```
<a href="#" onclick="func(@c.vid)"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" class="modalLink">
```

**Javascript code to pass the value is**

```
function func(vd){
        document.getElementsByClassName("hiddenid").value = vd;


    }
```

**Form is look like**

```
<form action="/Home/AddToCart" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" id="vid" name="vid" class="hiddenid" />
                            <div class="styled-input agile-styled-input-top">

                                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name"required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="styled-input">

                        <input type="text" placeholder="Star Name" onclick="showsss()" name="star" id="star" required>
                            </div>

                            <input type="submit"   value="Add To Cart">

                                </form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
         public ActionResult AddToCart(cart data)
         {
             userService.AddToCart(data);
             ViewBag.p = userService;
             return RedirectToAction("Temple");
         }
```

The value is passing to the hidden field perfectly.i checked using an alert box.am attaching a screen shot of what am getting in the controller.
[image: ScreenShot Here]

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return any array and not single element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByClassName return an array.

```
    function func(vd){
        document.getElementsByClassName("hiddenid")[0].value = vd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using byclass its return an array. try this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hiddenid")[0].value = vd;
```

But if you have a multiple products then do you have a add to cart button better to used id like vid-unique_number

Comment: but if you have a multiple products then do you have a add to cart button better to used id like vid-unique_number

Comment: Thank you sir.it works for me.How to return back to the same view from the controller?Because the current view  which has come along with an id.is there any way to return back to the same view?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Access single element using array index.

`document.getElementsByClassName("hiddenid")[0].value = vd;`

Instead of `className` you can use `id` as it is present on your hidden field i:e `vid`.

`document.getElementsById("vid").value = vd;`

or you can use `document.querySelector` which will retrieve first match element.

`document.querySelector('.hiddenid').value = vd;`

or

`document.querySelector('#vid').value = vd;`